# A questionable inside into overriding Equals

Tags: c#, overriding, equals

Following [Guidelines for Overriding Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx), it seems advisable to override gethashcode when overriding equals(object), as well as equals(type).

It is in my understanding that there is an endless discussion about what's the best implementation for overriding Equals. However, I still like to understand the Equals concept a little better and decide for my own.

My **questions** will probably be kinda noobish, but here we go:

- What is the main difference between Equals(object) and Equals(type) *(independently of the given parameters)*?

As far as I understand *(And I could be completely wrong, so this is a question at the same time)*:

> Equals(object) is a build in method that looks (at default) if object
>   references are the same. And Equals(Type) is a local method you
>   create. So in fact, what you have in that class is the method Equals
>   with 2 overloads.

- Why do they check for property equality twice?

In *equals(object)* :

```
   return base.Equals(obj) && z == p.z;
```

and in *equals(type)* :

```
   return base.Equals((TwoDPoint)p) && z == p.z;
```

- Why is it advisable to implement the Equals(type) method?
- Most of my questions are rapped in my statement in question 1. So note any wrong or misleading arguments plz. Also, feel free to add any information, it will certainly help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets distinguish the 2 methods

[`object.Equals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) is a method on the root `object` which is marked as `virtual` and therefore can be *overriden* in a derived class.

[`IEquatable<T>.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx) is a method obtained by *implementing* the [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) interface.

The latter is used for determining equality inside a generic Collection; so say the documentation:

> The IEquatable<T> interface is used by generic collection objects such as Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, List<T>, and LinkedList<T> when testing for equality in such methods as Contains, IndexOf, LastIndexOf, and Remove. It should be implemented for any object that might be stored in a generic collection.

The former is used for determining equality everywhere else.

So with the groundwork in place lets try to answer some of your specific questions

> What is the main difference between Equals(object) and Equals(type) (independently of the given parameters)?

One operates on any type, the other compares instances of the same type

> Why do they check for property equality twice?

They dont, generally only one is used. However quite often one implementation calls the other internally

> Why is it advisable to implement the Equals(type) method?

The answer is above - if you intend to store the object in a generic collection

As a side note, and one which may help you understand this, the default behaviour of equality checking is to check that the *references* are the same (ie, that one object is exactly the same instance as another). Quite often overriding/implementing different equality logic is used to compare some data within fields of the object (akin to your example of `z == p.z`)

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I didn't know about the IEquatable<T> interface. So I need to implement this in my class to be able to use the Equals(type) method? Is this standard implemented? What if this is not implemented, then the Equals(type) becomes just a custom made method in given class? Secondary, you say most of time, only one equals is used, how is determined which equals? Or do you mean that the programmer normally only implements the correct equals (so only one of the 2?)?

Comment: Unless your class implements `IEquatable<T>` nothing will know to use your `Equals(Type)` method - there's no point just adding that method. Im sorry, I dont understand your second question there.

Comment: thank you. Well, to clarify my 2nd question, you answered on my 'why do they check prop equality more then once': 'They dont, generally only one is used.' How is determined which equals method (does .Net determines this on intelligence?) is used. Or do you mean that a programmer only implements the correct (so eather equals(type) OR equals(obj)) method. (depending on if current class is implemented in a list)

Answer (score 0):

One difference between the overloads is that, as noted, one will be invoked when comparing an object to things which are known at compile time to be of the same type, while the other will be invoked in all other circumstances.  Another very important difference which has not been mentioned is that `Equals(ownType)` will act not only on things of `ownType`, but also on things that are implicitly convertible to `ownType`.  Because of this, `Equals` cannot not be expected to implement an equivalence relation among objects of convertible types unless one forces its operands to be of type `Object`.  Consider, for example,

```
(12.0).Equals(12);
```

converts the integer value 12 to the `Double` value 12.0.  Since the type and value of the passed value precisely match the `12.0` whose `Equals` method is being invoked, thus returning `true`.

```
(12).Equals(12.0);
```

Because `Double` is not implicitly convertible to `Int32`, passes the `Double` value as `Object` instead.  Since the `Double` does not match the type of the `12` whose `Equals` method is being invoked, the method returns `false`.

The virtual method `Equals(Object)` implements an equivalence relation; in many cases involving implicit type conversions, the type-specific methods cannot be expected to do so.